# Check or set entries in nested dict from list of keys of variable length

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dict that corresponds to a directory tree like this:

```
a:
  b:
    c: 1
    d: 1
  e:
    f:
      g: 1
      h: 1
...
```

in this case all keys that get a number as value (c, d, g, h) are files, all other entries are folders. Now given a path like "a/e/f/g" I want to do the following:

- check if my_dict[a] exists, otherwise create it
- check if my_dict[a][e] exists, otherwise create it
- check if my_dict[a][e][f] exists, otherwise create it
- check if my_dict[a][e][f][g] exists, otherwise create it and assign a default value to it

The length of the path for different files is not constant, so I can't do a simple chained .get(). Also I have to add the entries file by file.

I believe I am thinking way too complicated. Is there any elegant way of doing this?

Edit:
Example:

I have the nested dict from above and a file with path "a/b/i/j" and a default= 1. Then the dict should be updated like this:

```
a:
  b:
    c: 1
    d: 1
    i:
      j: 1
  e:
    f:
      g: 1
      h: 1
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
my_dict = {}
path = "a/e/f/g"
wd = my_dict  # Set working dictionary to my_dict
path_split = path.split('/')
for char in path_split[:-1]:  # Loop through all but the final char in the path
    if char not in wd or not isinstance(wd[char], dict):
        wd[char] = {}
    wd = wd[char]  # Set new working dictionary
if path_split[-1] not in wd:  # Check if final char is in the wd, if not set it to 1
    wd[path_split[-1]] = 1
```

You need to check that a key exists in the working dictionary and that the corresponding value is a dictionary, then set the working dictionary after each check.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. i agree that this would work if my dict had only one entry on each level. however each level can have multiple entries which would be overwritten if done this way.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, I will see if I can fix that.

Comment: yes, here a very simple example: if  i have the dict {a: {b: {c: 1}, d: {e:1}}} and i add entries from "a/f/g" then i would end up with the dict {a:{f:{g:1}}}. all other entries like b,c,d,e would be "overwritten"

Comment: I figured it out, I was trying to use `is` in order to check the type of a value, which is not what `is` does; I edited the answer and the code should work now.

Comment: @Omnikar as per @Nik if you use that `dict` then your output will be wrong.

Comment: `path = "a/e/f/g"` when this path is used, we can see that it is all ready present, so no change in `my_dict` but your output is `{'a': {'b': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}, 'e': {'f': {'g': 1, 'h': 1}}}}`

Answer (score 0):

I have taken such `dict` you should change it according to you requirement. I have taken a `path = 'Folder1/Folder12_/Folder121/File1211'` where `Folder12_` is not present in superdirectory.

```
df = {
    'Folder1': {
        'Folder11': {
            'File111': 1,
            'File112': 1,
        },
        'Folder12': {
            'Folder121': {
                'File1211': 1,
                'File1212': 1,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
path = 'Folder1/Folder12_/Folder121/File1211'.split('/')

df_test = df
ind_last = 0
for i in path:
    ind_last = path.index(i)
    if df_test.get(i):
        df_test = df_test.get(i)
    else:
        break

for i in path[ind_last:]:
    if path.index(i) != 3:
        df_test[i] = {}
        df_test = df_test.get(i)
    else:
        df_test[i] = 1
        df_test = df_test.get(i)
print(df)
```